# An alternative for Mail.lib for accessing Gmail emails?

Tags: c#, email, gmail, imap

I am working with C# and I have found Mail.dll from here http://www.limilabs.com/mail
which is just the perfect thing. Unfortunately it's not free. Is there any way that I can get the full thing for free ? or is there a similar library ?
Btw I am working with Gmail and IMAP :)

Comment: You can say that our comment tone is not proper, but this question is also off-topic asking for off-site resource. I do not have any close votes left for today, but will definitely vote on it tomorrow if it does not get closed. Most of your questions are effortless and/or off-topic. Please carefully read the help center for changing this habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are built in namespaces (ex. `System.Net.Mail`) for sending emails; take a look at [this tutorial](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-smtp-mail.htm).

[addendum] If you want to receive messages, check out something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14304/POP3-Email-Client-NET-2-0), which can be used to receive messages through POP3.

Comment: I don't really care for sending msgs I really need to be able to get all msgs in the gmail inbox

Comment: sry but i have looked over all similar things including those ones you told me about and they arenothing compared to what Mail.dll is, thx for trying to help though